# Как прочитать значение в BIOS?

Tags: windows

Здравствуйте!

Утилита меняет режим работы в зависимости от значения в BIOS (марка ноутбука). Как его оттуда прочитать?

Спасибо.

Comment: EFI уже наступает всё плотнее и плотнее! Готовьтесь :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Теневой (шадов) биос располагается в верхних адресах физической памяти. Ядро использует отображение физиклмемори в системное ап для чтения некоторой информации из него (WMI). Как обычно это выполняется посредством `MmMapIoSpace()`, см. в врк smbios.c

Также можно выполнить чтение из U-mode используя секцию \PhysicalMemory, но в старших версиях системы она не доступна.

Comment: Почитал про WMI, похоже, я смогу читать из BIOS через него.